# $(TargetFramework) is empty when targeting multiple frameworks

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I have a project targeting multiple frameworks using `<TargetFrameworks>` (plural) in my `.csproj` file.

This works fine, but I'm unable to do framework-specific things in `.csproj` since the `$(TargetFramework)` property is always empty.

If I target a single framework using `<TargetFramework>` (singular) everything works as expected.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net5.0;net6.0;net7.0</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="DoSomethingFrameworkSpecific" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Text="$(TargetFramework)" /><!-- Empty string -->
    </Target>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="MyProject.targets">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>build\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath><!-- File ends up in \build, not build\net5.0 etc -->
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I was under the impression that **MSBuild** would pass the current framework version for each pass (i.e. for each framework) so that we can do things like framework-specific paths or other conditionals depending on the version being built?

The official docs suggest this is possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-a-target-framework

Related questions on SO seem to deal with preprocessor directives only, not getting the current framework version in MSBuild scripts.

Comment: Does it work if you use it in a condition like in the example : `<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net50' ">` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've also tried with conditional for if `$(TargetFramework) != ''`, but it never triggers.

Comment: Is this your *actual* project file? In my tests this project file does absolutely nothing (it doesn't even compile anything) because it needs to start with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`. Opening it in Visual Studio just gives a cryptic error message (presumably because it attempts to parse it as an old-style project file and fails).

Comment: No, it's been shortened for clarity, but I added the `Sdk` attribute to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Comment: For the record, on my system, if the `Message` is amended to include `Importance="High"` (because otherwise it's only visible if the verbosity is cranked up to diagnostic level) a `dotnet build` dutifully emits one message for every framework built. Likewise, adding `Condition=" $(TargetFramework) != 'net5.0'"` to it omits the message specifically for .NET 5.

Comment: Tested with MSBuild 17.4.1+fedecea9d and MSBuild version 17.5.0-preview-22620-02+a6f6699d1, in case it matters (SDK versions 7.0.103 and 7.0.200-preview.22628.1, respectively).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use `$(TargetFramework)` in a nuget pack path when targeting multiple TFMs, change `<None>` to `<TfmSpecificPackageFile>` otherwise it won't work. By default nuget will evaluate files to pack from the outside build not the TFM-specific build, but if you use `<TfmSpecificPackageFile>` then it will re-evaluate the pack item from the inner TFM-specific build.

As for the message - I tested it and it works fine, although I do get an empty message at the end for the outer build plus the TFM-specific messages above that in the output. If you want to remove the empty outer build message then just add a condition. Final result should look something like this:

```xml
    <Target Name="DoSomethingFrameworkSpecific" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != ''">
        <Message Text="Message from TFM: $(TargetFramework)" />
    </Target>

    <ItemGroup>
        <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="MyProject.targets">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>build\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
        </TfmSpecificPackageFile>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I'm trying something similar but can't get it to work: A custom target for generating some files without building. That is, I'd like to runs a command for each project like, just like DoSomethingFrameworkSpecific in the original question. Running msbuild "/target:DoSomethingFrameworkSpecific" only works correctly with <TargetFramework>, but when using <TargetFrameworks>, $(TargetFramework)"is empty. If I specify "/target:Build" it does work, but I don't want the whole build...

Comment: @JohanLundberg I'm not really an msbuild expert but I'm guessing you need to give it an appropriate order so that it runs after the inner builds are triggered. `/target:DispatchToInnerBuilds;DoSomethingFrameworkSpecific` might work as well, idk.